# Eclipse Browser shows precompiled angular code

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, google-chrome

I have followed all the instructions of the following page to setup an Angular development environment: 
**https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started** and when I run my app on a local apache server the browser shows the angular precompiled code.

If I browse that app in Google Chrome it works perfectly.

What have I forgotten?

This is the code of the app:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Guess The Number !</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<div class="container" ng-controller="GuessTheNumberController">
    <h2>Guess the Number !</h2>
    <p class="well lead">Guess the computer generated random number between 1 and 1000.</p>
    <label>Your Guess: </label><input type="number" ng-model="guess"/>
    <button ng-click="verifyGuess()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Verify</button> 
    <button ng-click="initializeGame()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Restart</button> 

        <p ng-show="deviation>0" class="alert alert-warning">Your guess is higher.</p>
        <p ng-show="deviation<0" class="alert alert-warning">Your guess is lower.</p>
        <p ng-show="deviation===0" class="alert alert-success">Yes! That"s it.</p>

    <p class="text-info">No of guesses : <span class="badge">{{noOfTries}}</span><p>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('app',[])
        .controller('GuessTheNumberController', GuessTheNumberController);
        function GuessTheNumberController($scope) {
            $scope.verifyGuess = function () {
                $scope.deviation = $scope.original - $scope.guess;
                $scope.noOfTries = $scope.noOfTries + 1;
            }
            $scope.initializeGame=function() {
                $scope.noOfTries = 0;
                $scope.original = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
                $scope.guess = null;
                $scope.deviation = null;
            }
            $scope.initializeGame();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And Eclipse Browser shows the following:

```
Guess the Number !
Guess the computer generated random number between 1 and 1000.
Your Guess: Verify Restart 
Your guess is higher.

Your guess is lower.

Yes! That"s it.

No of guesses : {{noOfTries}}
```

Local console log:

```
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTENCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:AngularJS' did not find a matching property.
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTENCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:GuessTheNumber' did not find a matching property.
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server built:          May 19 2015 14:58:38 UTC
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Server number:         8.0.23.0
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: OS Name:               Windows 7
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: OS Version:            6.1
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Architecture:          x86
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: JVM Version:           1.8.0_45-b15
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Uda\Workspaces\angularJS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Programacion\apache-tomcat-8.0.23
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Uda\Workspaces\angularJS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Programacion\apache-tomcat-8.0.23
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Uda\Workspaces\angularJS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Programacion\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\endorsed
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
may 28, 2015 11:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMACIÓN: La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Uda\AppData\Roaming\npm;.
may 28, 2015 11:54:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
may 28, 2015 11:54:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMACIÓN: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
may 28, 2015 11:54:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
may 28, 2015 11:54:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMACIÓN: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
may 28, 2015 11:54:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMACIÓN: Initialization processed in 2521 ms
may 28, 2015 11:54:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Arrancando servicio Catalina
may 28, 2015 11:54:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
may 28, 2015 11:54:41 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFORMACIÓN: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [168] milliseconds.
may 28, 2015 11:54:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
may 28, 2015 11:54:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
may 28, 2015 11:54:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 1248 ms
```

Chrome console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Have you loaded angular script? check your network console... also check browser console for any errors.

Comment: yes... don´t know where the problem is...

Comment: By "check" i meant look out for any 404 or errors in the console and post that in the question. Also try to replicate it in a fiddler/plunker etc

Comment: I have updated with log text, I want 10 reputation points to post the picture...